# Why cordova is not defined?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I try build project android from IONIC. I want make app running in background and I use [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) but after include some code show error message in debugger. Error message like this `cordova is not defined`. I just include code like this

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

}, false);
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

I don't know why cordova is not defined. Please help me to solve this problem, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: are you running your project on a browser?

If you are running your project on a browser, you will get this error because Cordova needs to be run on a device or a simulator.